# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have developed an app in Unity and it runs fine but now when I tried to upload it, it gives this error

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. 
>   You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `Project settings > Player > Publishing settings > Alias` should not be in `Debug`.