# Unity:You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

I'm using Unity3D Engine 2018 to develop my Android application. But when I'm trying to upload my application to the Google play console I'm getting the following error,
[image]
When I click the learn more it directs me into [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) page but it is only about how to sign your APK bundle into release mode using Android Studio but not in Unity. Additionally [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590870/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-that-was-signed-in-debug-mode-you-nee), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681282/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-was-signed-in-debug-mode-you-need-to-sign-your-apk-in) I referred these questions but those do not contain a single solution to my problem.
Finally, I used to search in Unity Forum and I found [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-signing.62137/) and I followed these steps one by one,

> 1) Locate the Publishing Settings under PlayerSettings
>   2) Create a new keystore by selecting a keystore name and password (confirm the password)
>   3) Select "Create a new key" under Key Alias
>   4) A new window opens; enter the necessary information.
>   5) Select the newly created key.
>   6) Build ( Run); your app is now signed.

Then I have uploaded the newly created APK file into google play console but still, the error message remains.

**Note: I have opt-out the option that google manage my app signing key option** 
[image]

**Edit:** As @0xBFE1A8 requested my publisher settings are follows,
[image]

Comment: Please add the publisher settings image here.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I have added my publisher setings

Comment: Make a screenshot of the window where you press Build & Run too.

Comment: @Rixment plese check this link 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MvNrjX6xJmRhC2S85kRebfuOR9DbT86W

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you **Disable Development Build** before building. [image]